# Xml Transformation - copying parent attribute to child

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I want to transform the xml below by copying the attribute **Type** of every parent **PurchaseHistory** to their children **StoreTransaction**

**Input Xml:**

```
<ArrayOfStoreTransaction CustomerID="C1">
    <PurchaseHistory Type="purchase.001" Count="2">
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>C1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>C1A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>C1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>C1A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
    </PurchaseHistory>
    <PurchaseHistory Type="purchase.002" Count="1">
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
    </PurchaseHistory>
    <PurchaseHistory Type="purchase.003" Count="2">
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction>
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
    </PurchaseHistory>
</ArrayOfStoreTransaction>
```

**Output Xml:**

```
<ArrayOfStoreTransaction CustomerID="C1">
        <StoreTransaction Type="purchase.001">
            <CustomerID>C1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>C1A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction Type="purchase.001">
            <CustomerID>C1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>C1A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction Type="purchase.002">
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction Type="purchase.003">
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
        <StoreTransaction Type="purchase.003">
            <CustomerID>S3</CustomerID>
            <CustomerAccount>S3A</CustomerAccount>
        </StoreTransaction>
</ArrayOfStoreTransaction>
```

So I want a good library for java to transform my xml in an efficient way considering the memory and the execution time because the xml will be very big > 200mb

Comment: Do you run into memory or performance problems using XSLT as provided by the Transformer class in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Two simple XSLT template rules are all you need:

```
<xsl:template match="PurchaseHistory">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="StoreTransaction">
  <StoreTransaction Type="{../@Type}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </StoreTransaction>
</xsl:template>
```

A good modern XSLT transformation engine should be able to handle 200Mb without difficulty. If it gets into the gigabyte range, this transformation is fully streamable if you use an engine that supports XSLT 3.0 streaming.

Don't waste your time coding this in Java.